# Ошибка подключение к БД в symfony

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony, symfony3

Вылил сайт на хостинг и появилась ошибка подключения к базе данных.

> You have requested a non-existent parameter "database_name". Did you mean one of these: database

Локально всё работает нормально. В чём может быть ошибка?

Comment: в app/config надо копирнуть parameters.yml.dist как parameters.yml и прописать параметры.

Comment: создать 2 файла  parameters.yml.dist и parameters.yml ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Скорее всего неправильно задан конфиг  в parameters.yml  либо в config.yml.

в parameters.yml добавьте:

```
parameters:
    database_host: YOUR_HOST
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: DB_NAME
    database_user: DB_USER
    database_password: DB_PASS
```

а в config.yml добавьте подключение к доктрине

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_name%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
```

Comment: Всё равно не помагает

Comment: Всё получилось, я просто файл неправильно назвал в первый раз.  Спасибо